# Two parallel ajax requests to Action methods are queued, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm developing a video website using ASP.NET MVC.

One functionality I want to have in my application is transocding video. But as the transcoding process could be very time-consuming, I want to show the progress of that process to the client user.

So, my schema is to use one controller action to handle the whole transcoding process and write its progress into a file stored on the server. Meanwhile I use Ajax to call another controller action to read the specified file, retrieve the progress information and send it back to the client for display every 2 seconds during the transcoding process.

To fulfill my plan, I have written the following code:

Server Side:

```
public class VideoController : Controller
{
         //Other action methods
         ....
    //Action method for transcoding a video given by its id
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Transcode(int vid=0)
    {
        VideoModel VideoModel = new VideoModel();
        Video video = VideoModel.GetVideo(vid);
        string src = Server.MapPath("~/videos/")+video.Path;
        string trg = Server.MapPath("~/videos/") + +video.Id+".mp4";
        //The file that stores the progress information
        string logPath = Server.MapPath("~/videos/") + "transcode.txt";
        string pathHeader=Server.MapPath("../");

        if (await VideoModel.ConvertVideo(src.Trim(), trg.Trim(), logPath))
        {
            return Json(new { result = "" }); 
        }
        else
        {
          return Json(new { result = "Transcoding failed, please try again." });
        }
    }

    //Action method for retrieving the progress value from the specified log file
    public ActionResult GetProgress()
    {
        string logPath = Server.MapPath("~/videos/") + "transcode.txt";
        //Retrive the progress from the specified log file.
        ...
        return Json(new { progress = progress });
    }
}
```

Client Side:

```
var progressTimer = null;
var TranscodeProgress = null;

// The function that requests server for handling the transcoding process
function Transcode(vid) {
    // Calls the Transcode action in VideoController
    var htmlobj = $.ajax({
        url: "/Video/Transcode",
        type: "POST",
        //dataType: 'JSON',
        data: { 'vid': vid },
        success: function(data)
        {
        if(data.result!="")
            alert(data.result);
        }
        else
        {
          //finalization works
          ....
        }
    }
    });
    //Wait for 1 seconds to start retrieving transcoding progress
    progressTimer=setTimeout(function ()
    {
        //Display progress bar
        ...
       //Set up the procedure of retrieving progress every 2 seconds
        TranscodeProgress = setInterval(Transcoding, 2000);
    }, 1000);
}

//The function that requests the server for retrieving the progress information every 2 seconds.
function Transcoding()
{
    //Calls the GetProgress action in VideoController
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Video/GetProgress",
    type: "POST",
    //dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data)
    {
        if (data.progress == undefined || data.progress == null)
            return;
        progressPerc = parseFloat(data.progress);
        //Update progress bar
        ...
    }
  });
}
```

Now the Client-side code and the `Transcode` action method all work fine. The problem is that the `GetProgress` method will never get called until the `Transcode` action finishes its whole procedure. So what's wrong with my code? How can I modify it to make those two actions work spontaneously so as to achieve my goal?

**Update**

Based on Alex's answer, I found that my problem is caused by the session lock mechanism of Asp.Net framework. So disabling the `SessionState` of my `VideoController` or setting it as read-only does make the controller responses to the request for retrieving transcoding progress when the action method of transcoding video is being executed. But because I use `Session` in my `VideoController` to store some variables for use across multiple requests, this way couldn't be a suitable solution for my problem. Is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: Ivan, you should accept @AlexArt. `s answer, since it solved your problem

Comment: @Menahem Sure I did. But I still need to find the optimal solution for my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You misunderstood the whole point about async/await. It doesn't change the fact that for each single request, there is a single response that is returned. When you call await in your action, nothing is returned to client yet. The only thing it does (in a very high level abstraction) is to release the current thread that handles this request to a thread pool so it could be used for processing other requests. So basically it allows you to use your server resources more efficiently since there are no threads that are wasted waiting for long I/O operations to complete. Once the I/O operation is completed the the execution of the action (that called for await) continued. Only at the end of an action the response is sent to the client.

As for you scenario, if it is a long running task, I would use some kind of background processing solution such as [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) and use SignalR to push updates from server.[Here is an example](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/tracking-progress.html)

You can also implement something similar on your own ([example](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/06/server-side-signalr/)).

**UPDATE**:
As @Menahem stated in his comment I maybe misinterpreted part of your question.

Request queuing issue may be caused by incorrect configuration of [SessionStateBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatebehavior(v=vs.110).aspx). Since [MvcHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchandler(v=vs.118).aspx) handler which is used by ASP.NET MVC is marked with [IRequiresSessionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, only one request at time could be processed per session. In order to change that, make you controller sessionless (or ar least make sure that you are not writing into session in this controller) and mark it with 
`[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` attribute.

Comment: You may be right about what the OP got wrong, but to note, he is using Ajax on the client to achieve the parallel processing of the 2 requests. So this is not an answer to why his requests are being queued.

Comment: @Menahem, I get your point. Will update the answer accordingly

Comment: I tested it by putting `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]` above the `VideoController` and the `GetProgress`action does get called when the `Transcode` action is ongoing. So I got the reason that caused my problem. But as I use `TempData` which uses `Session` internally in my `VideoController` to store some variables I need to use across requests, setting the whole controller as read-only to `Session` may not suit my case.

Comment: You can use cookie based TempDataProvider instead of default one https://brockallen.com/2012/06/11/cookie-based-tempdata-provider/

Comment: I just had a deep check on my `VideoController` and found that I did use `Session` in several other action methods as well.

Comment: You can create a new separate controller

Answer (score 1):

File creation is blocking call. In other words, until first thread will not close file, second one which makes report will not be able to read contents of that file. As workaround you can create files with percentage of progress. For example movie1-5-percent.txt, movie1-10-percent.txt,  movie1-15-percent.txt etc, in order to avoid blocking calls to file system. Then you can check, if for movie1 there is file movie1-15-percent.txt, then you can report to ajax call, that 15 percent of movie was converted.  Or choose another non blocking storage. For example you can report result to db in first thread, and read results from db in another.