# After using window.location the async function behaving as sync function

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asynchronous

I worked on a `ASP.NET MVC 4` project in which users can apply filter on UI & extract an excel report. The data was stored in `MS SQL server`. To improve performances, i decided to adopt the `async` in my application to:

1. Reduce the time of extraction
2. Allow users to have parallel extraction

To do this, my approach are:

1. When user click extraction button on UI -> an `ajax` call will be made from client to `async` function on server -> This `async` function in turn will create an `Command` object & do `ExecuteReaderAsync()`. Using this `DbDatareader` to generated an Excel file using `NPOI` and save the file content to `TempData`. The handler to retrieve file will be return to client for later download using `window.location`. I adopted these techniques from this post [Download Excel file via AJAX MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670209/download-excel-file-via-ajax-mvc)
2. After the first extraction, if users want to extract another datasets in parallel, they can click extraction button again and application will repeat step 1.

The results are 2 or more data extractions can happened on the same time.

My problem is, take example, 4 extractions currently running in parallels, if any of these extractions finished & 1 file is downloaded (using `window.location`). The next time user click on extraction button (which repeat step 1), it doesn't async anymore & later extractions will wait for previous extraction finish before execute.

On debugging, if i restart the ISS server, the problem gone for a while until 1 file is downloaded, so I doubted that `window.location` do something that blocked the threads on server when any of file is downloaded.

**UPDATE 1**

Class:

```
public class QUERYREADER
{
    public DbConnection   CONNECTION { get; set; }
    public DbDataReader   READER { get; set; }
}
```

Model:

```
public async Task<QUERYREADER> GET_DATA(CancellationToken ct)
{
    //Create the query reader
    QUERYREADER qr  = new QUERYREADER();

    //Set up the database instances
    DbProviderFactory dbFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(db.Database.Connection);

    //Defined the query
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Table";

    //Set up the sql command object
    using (var cmd = dbFactory.CreateCommand())
    {
        //Try to open the database connection 
        try
        {
            //Check if SQL connection is set up
            if (cmd.Connection == null)
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection  = db.Database.Connection;
            } 
            //Open connection to SQL if current state is closed
            if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                //Change the connection string to set the packet size to max. value = 32768 to improve efficiency for I/O transmit to SQL server 
                cmd.Connection.ConnectionString = cmd.Connection.ConnectionString + ";Packet Size=20000";
                //Open connection
                await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync(ct);
            }
            //Save the connection 
            qr.CONNECTION = cmd.Connection;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //If errors throw, close the connection
            cmd.Connection.Close();
        };


        //Retrieve the database reader of provided sql query
        cmd.CommandText = query;       
        DbDataReader dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(ct);
        qr.READER.Add(dr);       
    }  

    //Return the queryreader
    return qr;
}
```

Controller:

```
  public async Task<JsonResult> SQL_TO_EXCEL()
  {        
       //Set up the subscription to client for "cancellation request, browser closing"
        CancellationToken   disToken = Response.ClientDisconnectedToken;             

        //Get the datareader
        try 
        {
            qr  = await GET_DATA(disToken);        
        } 
        catch(Exception ex) { }

        //Open the connection to SQL server
        using (qr.CONNECTION)
        {
            using (var dr = qr.READER)
            {                                            
                while (await dr.ReadAsync(disToken))
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < dr.FieldCount; k++)
                    {
                        //.... using NPOI to write Excel file to MemoryStream
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
        }

        //Generate XL file if controller action is still running (no "cancellation request, browser closing")
        if (!disToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {

            string file_id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            //... Write the NPOI excel file to TempData and then create a handler for later download at client
            //This line caused trouble
            TempData["file_id"] = XLMemoryStream.ToArray();

            HANDLER["file_id"]      = file_id;
            HANDLER["file_name"]    = FILE["FILE_NAME"].ToString().NonUnicode() + FILE["FILE_TYPE"].ToString() ;
        }

        //Return JSON to caller
        var JSONRESULT                  = Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(HANDLER), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            JSONRESULT.MaxJsonLength    = int.MaxValue;

        return JSONRESULT;
  }

    public async Task<ActionResult> DOWNLOAD_EXCEL(string file_id, string file_name)
    {
        if (TempData[file_id] != null)
        {
            byte[] data = await Task.Run(() => TempData[file_id] as byte[]);
            return File(data, "application/vnd.ms-excel", file_name);
        }
        else
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
    }
```

Javascript

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        url:  'SQL_TO_EXCEL',
        success: function (data)
        {
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
            window.location =
            (
                "DOWNLOAD_EXCEL"    +
                '?file_id='         + response.file_id +
                '&file_name='       + response.file_name
            );
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

UPDATE 2:

After a lot of tests, i figured out `window.location` has nothing to do with threads on server, the line `TempData[file_id] = XLMemoryStream.ToArray()` caused the issues. It look likes the problem is similar as described in this post [Two parallel ajax requests to Action methods are queued, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447801/two-parallel-ajax-requests-to-action-methods-are-queued-why)

Comment: can you clarify; are you talking about concurrent *requests* here? i.e. are we talking about the browsers http connection? or are you talking about activity at the server?

Comment: @MarcGravell I updated my code on the question. I think we talking on both concurrent ajax call at client & concurrent call on server controller. When user clicked on the extraction button, a new `ajax` request will be sent to server to trigger async `SQL_TO_EXCEL()` on controller and return an handler to client with `file_id` and `file_name`, then browser will point to `DOWNLOAD_EXCEL()` with these parameters to download the file. As i mentioned, users can click extraction button multiple times to have multiple concurrent extraction.

Comment: To simplify, i assumed multiple clicks on extraction button will query the same data from `"SELECT * FROM Table"`